# SCons required Variables()

Tags: scons

I'm trying to set up a [build config file using the `Variables`  class in SCons](http://www.scons.org/doc/HTML/scons-user/ch10s02.html#idp2963616).

I'd like to know, **is there any way of requiring that a variable be set**, either via the command-line, or from the "config file" that I'm importing?

```python
cfg = Variables('build.cfg', ARGUMENTS)                 # include cmdline args
cfg.Add('SOMEVAR', 'Some build config variable (required)')
cfg.Add('OTHERVAR', 'Another build config variable (required)')

base_env = Environment(variables = cfg)
```

Of course I could manually check that the required build variables are set, but it seems like this would be a common requirement, better handled elsewhere:

```python
try:
    base_env['SOMEVAR']
    base_env['OTHERVAR']
except KeyError as e:
    raise StopError('Required variable not set: {0}'.format(e))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I went ahead and coded (and tested) this, replacing the previous answer.

```python
from SCons.Variables import Variables

class VariablesRequired(Variables):
    def __init__(self, files=[], args={}, is_global=1):
        self.required = []
        super(self.__class__,self).__init__(files, args, is_global)

    def Add(self, key, help="", default=None, validator=None, converter=None, required=False):
        Variables.Add(self, key, help, default, validator, converter)
        if required:
            print "adding required option ", key[0]
            self.required.append(key[0])

    def Update(self, env):
        print "required options are: ", self.required
        Variables.Update(self, env)
        for requirement in self.required:
            if not env.has_key(requirement):
                print 'violation: ', requirement

cfg = VariablesRequired('dummy.py', ARGUMENTS)
cfg.Add('x', 'first dummy is x', required = True)
cfg.Add('y', 'second dummy is y', required = True)
```

Result:

```
$ cat dummy.py
x=1

$ scons {project}
scons: Reading SConscript files ...
adding required option  x
adding required option  y
required options are:  ['x', 'y']
violation:  y
```

Comment: Hmm. Well, there has to be a list of required variables somewhere, so it would be easy to say "for requirement in required_list:" but I think the usual practice is to have defaults, not require an explicit value. But if you look at the source, it takes a validator.  I'll edit to add that.

Comment: The validator does not help in this case.  However, variables does keep track of all the un-set options.  Call UnknownVariables() and check that. It does not have a "required" flag on the option itself, so there will have to be some code outside variables.  You could however write a separate class derived from variables to do that checking.